# How to show html tag from database

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I got data in database (MongoDB) like this
`"name": "My name","desc": "<p>some description</p>\r\n"`

and when I want to show in **ejs** file code like this `<h2><%= pd.name %></h2> <%= pd.desc %>` and it display

> My name <p>some description</p>

I tried inspect element it show.. **"<p>some description</p>"** how to turn str to html tag

Comment: While I have no idea how to do this in ejs, the concept you're dealing with here is called "escaping html entities". It is a security measure, intended to prevent injection attacks. You can try to google for a way to tell ejs to render a string without escaping. But note that you only should do it if you are sure that there will be no malicious markup there (for example, you produce all the content, no user input is stored in this field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<%-` instead of `<%=`. For example,

```
<%- pd.desc %>
```

You can also check other variation of [tags in Ejs](https://github.com/mde/ejs#tags).